# Maven parent pom m2 vs .m2

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a Maven project shared with a team of people. While attempting to buildi it on Jenkins, I'm looking at the details of the project's parent pom. I'd like a confirmation of my interpretation of the following setting in parent pom:

```xml
<repository>      
    <id>m2-local</id>      
    <url>file:m2</url>
</repository>
```

To me, the above appears to refer to the parent's `m2` folder of the project. But the id `m2-local` makes no sense to me. There are no other references of `m2-local` anywhere else in the pom. I also looked for `m2-local` in `.m2/settings.xml`, but nothing for it there either. Is it possible that `m2-local` has no significance at all here? Also, `file:m2` is for Windows notation, but Jenkins is sitting on Linux. What should it look like on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

```xml
<repository>
    <id>m2-local</id>
    <url>file:m2</url>
 </repository>
```

This configuration is declaring a Maven repository, whose id is `m2-local` and that points to `file:m2`. The id is just an identifier and has no other meaning. What is more relevant is the URL.

It means that when Maven will try to look for dependencies, it will look for them at the URL `file:m2`, along with the URL of the other potential repositories. The URL `file:m2` points to a folder on the local machine called `m2` and located at the same place as the POM (this is because it is using a relative path). Such a notation is both valid in Windows and Linux.

Basically, it means that for your build to run on your Jenkins machine, you need to have a folder name `m2` located at the root of the project (location of the POM) and Maven will look inside for artifacts.

I suggest you read [Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) on the Maven documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, much appreciate it!